# Store connected select element binding stops working - Is this a bug? or my code?

Tags: lit-html

Select element bound to a state object loses update binding.

I am doing some exploration with lit-html and various routing/store combinations and have come across this strange behaviour. I have used the create-lit-app stackblitz.

I have a menu which is populated from an array on the store.state object. These links update a currentPage attribute on the store.

The navigation is self listens to the store and sets an [active] attribute if it matchs the store's currentPage.

Click events update the store. This is all working fine.

In another element (hello-world) I have a select box. The select box is populated by the same array on the store.state object. The [selected] attribute is set if the option matches the currentPage attribute. This also works fine.

I also put a couple of p tags which display the currentPage for sanity... or insanity... not yet sure.

Now, when I go back to using the menu the state changes and the menu [active] is working, as are the p tag updates in the other (hello-world) element. The select element however does not update. I can use the select to update the state but the binding down to the select seems to have stopped working all together.

I have tried super.update() and this.update() after googling similar issues but still no cheese. I am wondering if it is a function of an ugly anti-pattern on my part or if this might be an RC bug.

```
class HelloWorld extends LitElement {

constructor() {
    super();
    store.subscribe(() => super.update());
}

_updatePage(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  store.update(s => s.currentPage = e.target.value);
}

render() {

    return html`
  <p class="app-intro">
    Current page: ${store.state.currentPage}
  </p>
  <select @change=${(e) => this._updatePage(e)}>
    ${store.state.navItems.map(navItem => {
      return html`<option ?selected=${store.state.currentPage===navItem.page}>${navItem.page}</option>`
      })
    }
  </select>

        <p class="app-intro">
            Current page: ${store.state.currentPage}
        </p>
    `;
}

}
```

I want to be able to update the state from anywhere in the app and have all subscribers updated.

Comment: Are you using pwa-helpers to integrate LitElement with redux?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to set properties on your element when the store updates, that way your element is not tightly coupled to the store's structure.

Otherwise, you can use `this.requestUpdate()` to trigger an update. `update()` is just a lifecycle callback which is called by `LitElement` internally.